# how to get acquisition channels report from google analytics api

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

i want the data from google analytics api, under **Acquisition>Channels** and its detailed view also.
how can get that data using asp.net

Api names for the labels will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sanjay, Channel definition are **unfortunately** not yet available via API. You can find the [complete list of available dimensions and metrics on GA support page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

Comment: Havlik, can you please also tell me when the api will be available.

Comment: Sanjay, no clue :-) I suggest subscribing to RSS of API changelog (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/changelog) which will alert you whenever somethings changes.

BTW -- if you are happy with the answer, could please mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: ok thanx :) anyways i just manipulated the traffic source report to get the Channels report.

Comment: here's the link: 
http://sanjaybathre.blogspot.in/2014/02/acquisition-channels-report-using.html